# WCF and Ninject

Tags: wcf, ninject

within our per-session WCF services hosted in ISS, we would like to use Ninject to IOC different data access component through the interface.

Where would be the best place to declare the binding once? is it in Application_Start of Global.asax?

If it is, how could I obtain the instance through the inferface from Ninject?

I know in StructureMap, we can call something like ObjectFactory.GetInstance()?
What is the equivalent in Ninject?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have looked at the [official WCF extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf)? I usually define my own service factory (referenced in the .SVC file) and reference my Ninject module from there.

As for getting an instance from an interface (i.e. the opposite of having it injected), you do so via the kernel.  (You can always have an instance of IKernel injected into any of your classes by adding it to your constructor.)  Once you have it, you just use:

```
kernel.Get<IYourInterface>();
```